# cube root of i without refrence to i

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Is it possible to express the cube root of "i" without using "i" itself?

If this is possible can you show me how to arrive at it?

thanks

Comment: Any cube of a real number is again a real number, and $i$ is not a real number.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a polynomial having solution $i$ and then find a way to take the cube root of it...

Comment: (-1)$^{1/6}$...

Comment: Is $\operatorname{cis}\frac{\pi}{6}$ cheating?

Comment: @J.G.: Unfortunately, I think it is, since the $i$ in cis is in fact the $i$ of which we speak.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: I like that answer, but unfortunately, there are six of those, and only half of them are cube roots of $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the unit circle mark the $30$ degree, $150 $ degree and $270$ degree points. 
These are the cube roots of $i$

Comment: very cool answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. $i$ has 3 cube roots in the complex numbers and none of them can of course be real (i.e. have no imaginary part; a real number has a real third power, not $i$). They are

$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}, e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}, e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}} $$

which you can write out using Euler's $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$ as usual.